# always getting values of radiobuttonlist's server side in WPF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

Below is my XAML page code for radiobuttonlist:

```
<Label Content="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105" Margin="10,14,0,0"/>
    <Label Content="Age" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105" Margin="10,66,0,0"/>
    <Label Content="Gender" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105" Margin="10,115,0,0"/>
    <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="146" Margin="167,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="221,16,0,396"
             TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="120">
    </TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtAge" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="221,73,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <Button Name="btnSave" Style="{StaticResource Allbtn}" Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,190,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="32" Click="btnSave_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnExit" Style="{StaticResource Allbtn}" Content="Exit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="326,191,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="32" Click="btnExit_Click" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="grdGender" Height="41" Margin="221,115,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="223" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <ListBox Name="rdoGender" Margin="0,0,100,0">
            <RadioButton GroupName="rdoGender" Tag="M" Content="Male"/>
            <RadioButton GroupName="rdoGender" Tag="F" Content="Female"/>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
    <Button x:Name="btnClear" Style="{StaticResource Allbtn}" Content="Clear" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="198,191,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="32" Click="btnClear_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnTestWCF" Style="{StaticResource Allbtn}" Content="Test WCF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="221,244,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="32" Click="btnTestWCF_Click"/>
```

And below is code for Serverside to get selected value:

```
vEmployeeMasterSC.Gender = rdoGender.IsEnabled != true ? rdoGender.Tag.ToString() : "";
```

I am unable to get the selected radiobutton list's value to save into database.

Comment: You need to do some debugging and narrow the scope of your question. Attempting to solve your problem based on this information is going to be impossible.

Comment: I wish to implement selection of gender on the form and get the selected value on server side to save, Is there any easy way to implement this in WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give each radio button a name and use `IsChecked` on the RadioButton to determine which one is checked:

```
<RadioButton x:Name="rdoFemale" GroupName="rdoGender" Tag="M" Content="Male"/>
<RadioButton x:Name="rdoMale" GroupName="rdoGender" Tag="M" Content="Male"/>

vEmployeeMasterSC.Gender = rdoMale.IsChecked == true ? "Male" : "Female";
```

Comment: Unable to get IsChecked Property

Comment: I thought that rdoGender was the name of the RadioButton, but its a RadioButtonGroup name. I'll change my answer

Comment: Thanks for the Idea Glen, hopefully it will solve my issue, But I am new to  WPF, So suppose I have more than 2 options (Like Marital Status) in that case what should I do?

Comment: Use 'if' to determine the selected value instead of the ternary operator

Comment: I'l have to loop through all options? Is there any simple way to achieve this ?

Comment: There is no simple way to get the checked radio button from a group